# R- Looping through sets of data

Tags: r

I want to fill up certain values in a matrix by indexing a vector. It should be a simple loop

```
mat1[ i, as.numeric(index_vec[i]) ] = data[i,"price"]
```

I believe that is the only command I need for the loop because it fills the first row of the matrix properly if I put 1's where all of the i's are. Does anyone know very basic loops in R? I could be wrong, but I think its just a matter of syntax.

Comment: `mat1[, as.numeric(index_vec)] = data[,"price"]` should work

Answer (score 0):

It's not an RStudio question but rather an R question. We would need to know the dimensions of `mat1` and `data` and the lengths of index_vec to know if this makes any sense. It appears you may be coming from another language where everything is done with for-loops using indices. That's not always the best way to work with R. If the length of index_vec is the same as the number of rows of `data` and the values of as.numeric(index_vec) are above 1 and at or below the number of columns of mat1, then a modified version the suggestion above to use:

```
mat1[ 1 , as.numeric(index_vec) ] <-  data[ ,"price"]
```

... should succeed as a column to row assignment. The lengths on the RHS need to equal the number of values assigned on the LHS. If my guess was wrong about the nature of `index_vec` and it's only a single number, then perhaps a column to column assignment:

```
mat1[  , as.numeric(index_vec) ] <-  data[ ,"price"]
```

Then there is a third possibility as well. If you `index_vec` is a set of column locations and the implicit row locations go from 1 to length(index_vec) hten you could do this:

```
 mat1[ cbind( seq_along(index_vec) , as.numeric(index_vec) )  ] <-  data[ ,"price"]
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying I misstated my problem. The second suggestion resulted in filling the entire matrix. The index_vec should only return one value per row but the rest of the matrix should remain 0's. That is why I thought looping would be easier.